# flash cs5 animations on ipad

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, ipad, flash-cs5

Hi all
Ive just started messing around with flash cs5 and trying to make a simple app for the ipad and have it eventually on the app store. The thing that has me concerned is that the animations seem to be struggling on the ipad.

im running it at 24 fps and there is zero physics and very simple AS3 for touch to stop animations. But the animations are running so slowly and the sound layer is no longer in sync with the animation.

Does anyone have any experience with this that can advise me on what the issue may be? why would a simple flash cs5 animation struggle as an ipad app? would the file type of the sound files be an issue?
any advise would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have updates on flash now.
Flash Professional 5.5 and adobe AIR 2.7.

You can see Adobe video demonstration the very same problem.Our team also faced same sort of performance problems [here](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/flash-platform-in-action/adobe-air-27-faster-app-performance-on-ios/)

Comment: ah man that looks good alright and it came out just as i finished the project the hard way. yay for bad timing. good to know for future though thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Flash. Period. (It's actually the interpreter but that's besides the point...)

For best results, you need to code using the native SDK in objective-C.

You can use Adobe's porting tools but it's not going to work right because you're not using the tools designed for the platform.

In my opinion, Flash porting (if that IS what you're referring to) is for lazy developers who can't be bothering making a native app. They use this mostly for converting a Flash app to work on iOS.